# Is this an incorrect way of implementing responsive design elements?

Tags: html, css

Because many times the actual elements are different between mobile friendly screen sizes and the full version of the site, I find myself wanting to just have two versions of the site in two separate divs.  Once the two versions are set, I'd use CSS to show / hide the correct version.  Is there anything wrong with this practice?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {   /* phones & small screens */
    #desktop{
        display:none;
    }

    #mobile{
        display:block;
    } 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  /* tablets, desktops, & larger screens */
    #desktop{
        display:block;
    }

    #mobile{
        display:none;
    } 
}

<div id="desktop">
    Desktop Site
</div>

<div id="mobile">
    Mobile Site
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, do you really need two complete different divs for responsive design? I'd prefer using one html markup which strechtes and shrinks automatically using percentages and do the fine tuning with media queries.

Comment: Extra Add-up use percentage to define your division width

Comment: The approach you're describing is made a lot more useful in a site that uses client-side templates to generate page content, because it allows you to avoid at least some of the duplication.

Comment: When the elements are different between the two, yes.  For example.  If there is a login box on the desktop version, I rather have a link on the mobile version instead.  Also, many of the background images are usually different for the mobile version. Would it be better to swap out many smaller divs rather than two large divs?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to reuse as much as possible, create one stylesheet for your preferred version and then hide/show and modify everything using media queries. This will prevent duplication and allows you to adhere to old adage: Don't Repeat Yourself. However, sometimes it's not necessarily bad to have two versions of some things, but again, you should do that with media queries for specific elements as you don't want to repeat yourself (ironically, I just did).

As mentioned in the comments, using stretchable layouts with percentages is pretty nice nowadays, and thanks to the `box-sizing: border-box` property, it's easier then ever to create a full-width site without sacrificing controls over the paddings that your boxes use, making it very easy to make everything look good and consistent.

If you mobile site is completely different from your main site, it might be better to separate them and put it on a different URL, this will reduce load for mobile browsers and desktop browsers alike, which is always a good thing.